# Unity, change the display camera for the scene and the target display in the Canvas C#

Tags: c#, canvas, unity-game-engine, camera, display

I have 2 cameras and 1 Canvas, and I want to change the display for the scene to the second camera when pressing a button, and at the same time, change the target display for the Canvas to the second camera as well, and I'm using C#.

I know that I have to use `GetComponent<Camera>` and `GetComponent<Canvas>` but i don't know how to set the indexes for these two.

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: This seems like it might be more suited to the [GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) StackExchange site.

Comment: @GoBusto ,Thanks, I will look into that. I will wait here if someone could help with it, if not then I will try there.

Comment: I watch the [tag:unity3d] tag both here and on GameDev. GameDev is still figuring out where to draw the line on programming questions, currently it's rather lenient in the "if its related to game development, its fine here" though a year ago such questions (including this one) would be redirected over to SO. I'll answer it either place, depending on where I see it first (assuming, of course, that I can).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than changing the index: just *disable the one camera and enable the other.* There's no point wasting GPU cycles rendering something that can't be seen (which is what a second active camera will do).

As for changing the Canvas target:

Change the canvas's [worldCamera](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Canvas-worldCamera.html) property, eg:

```
canvasGO.GetComponent<Canvas>().worldCamera = cam2.GetComponent<Camera>();
```

Comment: That's a good point with enabling and disabling cameras, i'v seen it before but i didn't think of your point, thanks.

Comment: <Salute> Note that you can enable/disable the component itself, not just the game object. In some cases this might be preferable. I know that for Canvas stuff, it's muuuch faster to disable the canvas component. [Great talk from the Unity guys](https://youtu.be/n-oZa4Fb12U) on the subject.